# shorter way to collect data and update a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

here is my way to submit a form.
In reality it has much more text inputs.

Everything works fine, but I hope there is a shorter way, especially on server side, regarding that `data-col` on client side is in fact a corresponding column name on server.

**html**

```
<form id='dform'>
<input type='text' class='dinp' data-col='nick'>
<input type='text' class='dinp' data-col='state'>
<input type='text' class='dinp' data-col='city'>
<input type='text' class='dinp' data-col='uname'>
<input type='text' class='dinp' data-col='pass'>
</form>
```

**js**

```
$('#msave').on('click', function(){
    let id=$('.aact').attr('data-id');
    let obj = {};
    $('.dinp').each(function(){
        let col = $(this).attr('data-col');
        obj[col] = $(this).val().trim();
    });
    obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
    $.post('a_users_pro.php', {fn: 'm_save', args: [id, obj]}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**php**

```
function m_save($id, $obj){
    global $db;
    $obj = json_decode($obj);
    $sql = "
update users 
   set nick = :anick
     , state = :astate
     , city = :acity
     , uname = :auname
     , pass = :apass 
 where id = :aid
";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st -> execute([
        ":aid" => $id,
        ":anick" => $obj->nick,
        ":astate" => $obj->state,
        ":acity" => $obj->city,
        ":auname" => $obj->uname,
        ":apass" => $obj->pass
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name` attribute of `input` elements with your `data-col` value and pass the serialized form data to the AJAX request. Here is a implementation:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="age">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('update.php', $('#myForm').serialize());
  });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST)) {
  // Validate request

  $sql = 'UPDATE users 
    SET
      name = :name,
      email = :email,
      age = :age
    WHERE id = :id
  ';

  $st = $db->prepare($sql);

  $st->execute([
    ':id' => $_POST['id'],
    ':name' => $_POST['name'],
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':age' => $_POST['age'],
  ]);
}

?>
```

In your example I can't see where `.aact` and `data-id` come from. I assumed that the `id` value would be available to the view so I passed it to the request as a hidden input.